# How to find the same users (multiple user id having same id) but different amount spent (ie rate)

Tags: sql-server

I am four tables client,timekeeper,rate exception and rate exception rates tables. I am doing inner join with rate exception rate and rates tables and then rates with timekeeper table and rate exception with client table. I want to find the list of timekeeper (same user id ) listed twice but having different rates. Let me know your thoughts?? ( I tried using the having function count(*) > 1, but did not work)
Thanks.

Below is the query

```
select distinct c. Number AS "Client Number", c. Display Name AS "Client Name",
a. Number AS "Timekeeper No",
a. Display Name AS "Timekeeper Name", 
d. Rate Override AS "Rate"
from Timekeeper a
inner join (select Display Name, count(*) AS dupe Count
           FROM Timekeeper 
            group by Display Name
        having count(*) > 1) ac ON a. Display Name = ac. Display Name
INNER JOIN Rates d
ON d. Timekeeper = a. Timekeeper
INNER JOIN Rates x
ON x. Rate ID = d. Rate ID
INNER JOIN Client c
ON x. Client = c. Client Index
INNER JOIN (select Display Name, count(*) AS dup
            from Client
            group by Display Name
            having count(*) > 1) cl ON c. Display Name = cl. Display Name
where a. Status = 'Active' and d. Rate Override IS NOT NULL
and c. Status Type = 'Active' and d. Finish Date IS NULL
group by c. Number, c. Display Name, a. Number, a. Display Name, d. Rate Override
order by c. Number, c. Display Name, a. Number, a. Display Name, d. Rate Override ASC
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result along with query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SQL questions are better served with sample data and desired results as tabular text. You should also be showing your existing query and the result it produces.

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)